# Filtering a combox in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have an ExtJs combobox. Its store loaded using JSON (using my store). I want to load all the values to the store, and then filter them with the text entered in the combo's textfield.

I don't want my combo to reload its store every time I type something. How can I do that?
And other thing that then I try to select element from combobox first time it's reload data from server.
PS: listener in my store for select first element of data from server.
Thanks.

Here's my store class :

```
Ext.define('KP.store.account.street', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'KP.model.account.combo',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        api: {

            read: '/account/combostreetdata'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'combolist',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },

    listeners: {
        'load': function (street_list) {
            var street_combo = Ext.getCmp('street');
            street_combo.select(street_list.getAt(0));
        }
    }
});
```

My view:

```
{
    id: 'street',
    xtype: 'combobox',
    width: 700,
    name: 'street',
    editable: true, 
    mode: 'local', 
    typeAhead: true, 
    emptyText: '?????',
    fieldLabel: '???',
    labelWidth: 120,
    size: 72,
    x: 20,
    y: 180,

    displayField: 'string_value',
    valueField: 'long_key',
    store: street_list
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ComboBox config error.

Not `mode: 'local',` but `queryMode: 'local',`.

I use such a fields in my combos:

```
queryMode: 'local',
forceSelection: true,
```

Typeahead works fine, no data loads during typeahead.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. But do you know why then I try to select element from combobox first time it's reload data from server?

Comment: Hmm. Try to put `proxy` config option inside model and remove it from store.